# Computing the characteristic polynomial

Tags: vector-spaces, eigenvalues-eigenvectors, characteristic-functions

Consider the following matrix A over the field $F_7$
$$ \left(\begin{array}{rrr}
     3 & 4 & 4 \\
     2 & 5 & 2 \\
     1 & 2 & 5
  \end{array}\right) .
$$

I'm asked to compute the characteristic polynomial χA of A

I understand that I need to find the characteristic equation of $\det(A- \lambda I)$ but do I need to work in $F_7$ from the start or can I change it at the end

not in field 7 I believe I got $-x^3+13x^2-39x+27$

can I change it to this $6x^3+6x^2+3x+6$ ?
would this be correct?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you have done is correct (assuming the $x$s in your final answer should be $\lambda$s).  But two points.

- I would say there is no need to avoid negatives in describing $F_7$, so your answer can be simplified to $-\lambda^3-\lambda^2+3\lambda-1$.  (However your instructor may disagree - better check.)
- IMHO it would actually be easier if you used $F_7$ from the start, reducing the numbers to "least absolute value" form:
  $$\eqalign{\det(A-\lambda I)
    &=\det\pmatrix{3-\lambda&-3&-3\cr 2&-2-\lambda&2\cr 1&2&-2-\lambda\cr}\cr
    &=(3-\lambda)(-3\lambda+\lambda^2)+3(1-2\lambda)-3(-1+\lambda)\cr
    &=-\lambda^3-\lambda^2+3\lambda-1\ .\cr}$$

Comment: Thanks for answering! Although I have a question, I was taught that det(A) is equal to the characteristic polynomial when $/lamda$ is zero, but in this case det(A) is zero while the polynomial would be -1

Comment: Not sure how you got $\det(A)=0$, I got $-1$ in accordance with the polynomial.